# scrollTop not writable and always zero. scrollHeight always the same number

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrolltop

```
            <script type="text/template" id="gameroom_template">
            <input id="chatedit" type="text" />
            <input id="chatsend" type="button" value="send.chat" /> 
            <input id="chatleave" type="button" value="Leave Room" /></br>
            <div id="chatroll" style="font-size: 20px;width: 500px; height: 100px; overflow-y: scroll; border: 1px solid black;">
            </div></br>
            <canvas id="gameboard" width="500" height="500" style=""></canvas>
            </script>


            jQuery("#chatedit").val('');
            var scrolltop = document.getElementById("chatroll").scrollTop;
            var scrollheight = document.getElementById("chatroll").scrollHeight;
            console.log(scrolltop);
            console.log(scrollheight);
```

I'm loading the template with backbone.js. I see it and can interact with it however my attempts to set scrollTop to some value other than zero are not working. What I am doing is using the console to run the code and then checking the value of scrollTop which always comes back zero. I have tried setting it with jQuery and JavaScript ways. Does anyone know why scrollTop is not writable? I'm noticing as well as I fill the div with text and move the scroll bar up and down to various levels the value of scrollHeight is always 16.

Thank you for posting....

Comment: Are you able to reproduce issue in jsfiddle? Could be a DOCTYPE issue. Check `$(window).height()`, is it returning expected result?

Comment: $(window).height() returning 580. If I have to go to fiddle this is going to be taking some time...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what value you are trying to get.  Are you trying to get the scroll position of the body?  The position in relation to the body of `chatedit`?

To get the body scroll position, you would use:

```
document.body.scrollTop
```

To get the position of the `chatedit` element, I'd suggest using jQuery:

```
$('#chatedit').offset().top
```

If you're trying to see where it sits in relation to the viewport, you would merge the two:

```
$('#chatedit').offset().top - document.body.scrollTop
```

Comment: So #chatedit is a div with its overflow-y style property set to scroll so then that div #chatedit I think is supposed to have a scrollTop property which can be used to change the position of the scroll. Why would scrollTop be not writable I wonder....

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.scrollTop says that if the element is not scrollable it will be 0.

Comment: In the provided html, #chatedit is a text input.  If there are multiple elements with the same ID, that could be the issue.

Comment: I created a JSFiddle of this (http://jsfiddle.net/6SF39/), but it seems to work fine for me.  I don't think we have enough context to resolve your issue.

Comment: I think I'm going to end up creating a fiddle for this problem with backbone.js

Comment: I believe your fiddle and that is what I want as far as functionality. For some reason #chatroll scrollTop is always zero on my localhost.

Comment: I got it working. I'm not sure what was wrong I think it was just that I didn't understand well enough yet the workings of the properties. Thank you for posting...